# GameObject.FindWithTag throwing weird errors

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I've got 2 first person controller scripts, one that handles functionality for basic movement, the other handling looking around. I also have a "CursorLockManager" script, that handles the cursor locking, as well as locking movement and looking (for when opening menus and such). At the beginning of the cursor lock script, in the start function, I have two GameObject.FindWithTag lines. One looks for the playerLook script, and the other looks for the playerMove script. I have them both set up the same way, but one of them isn't working.

First few lines of the CursorLockManager script:

```
public KeyCode menuKey;
public PlayerLook playerLook;
public PlayerMove playerMove;
public bool menuIsOpened;
public GameObject tempMenu;

private void Start()
{

    playerLook = GameObject.FindWithTag("Camera").GetComponent<PlayerLook>();
    playerMove = GameObject.FindWithTag("FP_Controller").GetComponent<PlayerMove>();

}
```

and the error Unity is throwing:

> UnityException: Tag: Camera is not defined

[image]

Line 17 of the CursorLockManager:

```
        playerLook = GameObject.FindWithTag("Camera").GetComponent<PlayerLook>();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any further clarification as to anything else, I'd be glad to provide it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to search by tags at all. If you ultimately want to find instances of a specific component, then search for that component instead, like this:

```
playerLook = FindObjectOfType<PlayerLook>();
playerMove = FindObjectOfType<PlayerMove>();
```

This searches directly for the component you want to use, so it's less sensitive to scene setup errors (like forgetting to create a tag called "Camera" or misspelling Unity's default "MainCamera" tag)

Or you can skip searching for them at all, and instead use a [Singleton](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html) or [Service Locator pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html) to retrieve references to these key script instances more efficiently.

---

In Unity 2021.3.18 and newer, **there's a faster alternative** to `FindObjectOfType` when you know there's only one instance of this type anyway:

```
playerLook = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerLook>();
playerMove = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerMove>();
```

This skips invoking a sort to ensure the "first" instance is returned, since there's only going to be one of them anyway, making it more efficient.